# document.write() no me deja añadir atributos

Tags: javascript

estoy creando un formulario con datos para luego exportarlos a una tabla, sin embargo, cuando añado el elemento `document.write("<input placeholder="Texto del input">");` no aparece nada. He intentado con distintos tipos de código en Javascript pero el problema persiste. Parece ser que no me deja añadir ningún atributo cuando creo un elemento. Lo que yo quiero hacer es el siguiente proceso: Crear un elemento con `document.write()` y luego añadir a ese nuevo objeto un atributo como por ejemplo "placeholder". ¿Hay alguna solución a este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código no te está funcionando porque usas comillas dobles tanto en la cadena que construye el elemento como en los atributos, creando una cadena que Javascript no entiende.

Una solución sería  encerrar lo que es el `input` entre comillas simples, por ejemplo:

```js
document.write('<input placeholder="Texto del input">');
```

Otra opción interesante en Javascript es usar las comillas invertidas (`)  para encerrar cadenas. Esto permite ademas el uso de variables dentro. Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
var inputName="nombre";
document.write(`<input placeholder="Escriba el ${inputName}">`);
```

**PD:** Quizá la mejor opción para lo que intentas hacer no es `document.write`, pero ese es ya otro tema.

Answer (score 1):

La función `document.write` ya no es muy recomendado su uso, ya que por lo general sustituye todo el html dentro de un documento o de dicha pagina donde se utilice.

Además como dice **@ACedano**:

> El código no te está funcionando porque usas comillas dobles tanto en la cadena que construye el elemento como en los atributos, creando una cadena que Javascript no entiende.

Lo que puedes hacer en lugar de usar `document.write`, es lo siguiente:

```js
var $input = document.createElement('input');
$input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Type your text here');
$input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
$input.setAttribute('value', '');
document.body.appendChild($input);
```